What is the most efficient way to key a xyz pair in a C# dictionary?
I have a bunch of objects with xyz pairs (bytes) that I need to add to a dictionary.  It's in the tens of thousands and I'm not sure what the most efficient way would be to go about it.
Would something like this work?
Dictionary<int, Object> table;

table.Add(new byte[3]{ x, y, z }.GetHashCode(), object);

Or would it be better to use a byte[3] and an equality comparer?

Arrays don't override GetHashCode(), so you'd up with the default hash code implementation from Object, which returns different values based on the object's identity (in other words, two different byte arrays containing the same items are likely to get different hash codes).

If the key is always 3 bytes, it seems like a ValueTuple is appropriate.
Dictionary<(byte, byte, byte), object> table;

table.Add((1,2,3), new object());

Unlike a byte[], ValueTuple is a value type, so it won't cause additional heap allocations when you access the dictionary.
You can also pack the 3 bytes inside an int with bit shifts. This might be faster than a value tuple.
byte b1 = ...;
byte b2 = ...;
byte b3 = ...;
int key = (b1 << 16) | (b2 << 8) | b3;

Dictionary<int, object> table = new();
table.Add(key, new object());


thanks very much Sweeper, u even provided code.  It works :)  The bitshift thing is really cool.  That's the main problem I was having.  Couldn't figure out how to combine the 3 bytes into a key.
